# Wirtinger equality with nule integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in {\mathcal{C}}^1([- \pi , \pi])$, with $f(- \pi) = f(\pi)$, such that $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) \, dt = 0$ and
$$
\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f(t)|}^2 \, dt = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} {|f'(t)|}^2 \, dt\mbox{.}
$$
I have to prove that exists $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) such that $f(t) = \alpha \cos t + \beta \sin t$ for all $t \in [- \pi , \pi]$. Also, if $g \in {\mathcal{C}}^1([a , b])$, with $g(a) = g(b)$, such that $\int_a^b g(t) \, dt = 0$, I have to prove that exists $c \geq 0$ such that
$$
\int_a^b {|g(t)|}^2 \, dt \leq c \int_a^b {|g'(t)|}^2 \, dt\mbox{.}
$$
Which is the condition to obtain equality in the last inequality? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\{\cos(nx),\sin(nx)\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is dense in $C^1([-\pi,\pi])$. So $f\in C^1([-\pi,\pi])$ can be written as
$$ f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty[a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)] $$
So
$$  f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty[-na_n\sin(nx)+nb_n\cos(nx)]. $$
Noting
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin^2(nx)dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^2(nx)dx=\pi, \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(mx)\sin(nx)dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)dx=0 $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(x)|^2dx&=&2\pi a_0^2+\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty[a_n^2+b_n^2],\\
\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f'(x)|^2dx&=&\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2[a_n^2+b_n^2],
\end{eqnarray}
and hence $\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(x)|^2dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f'(x)|^2dx$ if and only if
$$ a_0=0,a_n=b_n=0,n\ge 2. $$
Namely $f(x)=a_1\cos x+b_1\sin x.$

For the second part, shift $[a,b]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ and you will get it. I omit the detail.